# JWT Authorization Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

My question is on the `Authorization`.

I have two controller's `Account` and `Patient` Controller. I am trying to call
the `PatientController.GetData` and it say's `Unauthorized`.

I am sure I already attached `authorization:"jwttoken" on the Header`

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController{

   [AllowAnonymous]
   public JsonResult Login(){

   }

}

[Authorize]
public class PatientController{

    public IActionResult GetData(){

    }

}

startup file
here is my startup file:

    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {

                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false

                };
            });
```

thanks,
pong

Comment: This might be off topic but are you using the Cuongle attributes? Check this PR I made that solves a vulnerability, it remained unmerged https://github.com/cuongle/WebApi.Jwt/pull/4

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you've set up your Authorisation in the startup.cs file configureServices()

eg

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "Authentication Server Url";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Audience = "Client id";

            });
```